Sample size calculation for prevalence studies: how do I find d when reviewing a published study?
I have found the following formula in Munn et al.:
$$N = \frac{Z^2 P(1-P)}{d^2}$$

$N$ = sample size
$Z$ = statistic for a level of confidence
$P$ = expected prevalence
$d$ = precision

The problem I am finding is that I am trying to use this formula to assess the quality of several studies for a meta-analysis and all the studies I have reviewed so far do not provide a $d$ value, but only the total number of subjects, the number of subjects with the disease and the corresponding percentage. These are epidemiological studies on the prevalence of a disease in the general population and there is no exposure, so no comparison between cases in exposed and non-exposed subjects is made. The only data available is how many subjects in the sample exhibit the disease. Is there a way for me to calculate d by only using the information provided in the article?
I am aware of this formula:
$$
d= \frac{p_1-p_0}{\sqrt{ p_0(1-p_0)}}
$$

$p_1$=observed proportion
$p_0$=expected proportion if $H_1$ is false

Which is used for hypothesis testing with proportions, but I am not sure of what value should $p_0$ assume when evaluating published prevalence studies.

$d$ is not calculated; it is specified as a constant.  A reasonable choice of $d$, for example, when the true unknown prevalence is < 0.1 might be $d=0.01$. If the prevalence is likely to be < 0.01 then perhaps choose $d=0.001$.  You’ll see that very large samples are needed.
